# How to filter the errormessage in a Lua string

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

With luasec I recieve the following answer:

> blablabla..result="0"><header result="0"><office
>   msgtype="error" msg="Administratie 355140001 bestaat niet."
>   result="0">355140001</office><code>K..blablabla

How can I filter the text between the quotes behind `"msg="`?

With the function `string.find (responsetable,"msg=")` I can find the first character, but how can I read the rest of the string until the last quote. (the length of the errormessage is different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the content, use `string.match`:

```
str:match('msg="(.-)"')
--Administratie 355140001 bestaat niet.
```

Note that use of `-` for 0 or more lazy repetitions.

Comment: Thanks! The answer was easy:  errormsg = string.match(responsetable, 'msg="(.-)"');